# Sublime Text 3: how do I highlight current line number regardless of colour scheme?

Tags: user-interface, sublime-text-3

I already have `"highlight_line": true,` but the contrast is so poor, I would like to ask if there is a way I can set the current line number to become highlighted in significantly greater contrast than all other line numbers?

Comment: I could not find an option to change the highlight level on line number. What I could do was change the theme - this offered more contrast. See if this is to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no default option available for this (time of writing build 3120).

There might be a plugin available that does what you want, see [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search/open%20files).

You can also make a feature on the [forum](https://forum.sublimetext.com).